# Unable to test Rest api

Tags: php, json, api, rest

i am developing a REST API for my android application. At the moment i haven't incoropated it into my application instead i am trying to test it with the popular "Advanced Rest Client App" on chrome. The function handling the GET method works fine and displays records from my db in json format but when i try to test the function handling POST it doesn't work. Please i would like some one to help me out on how to test my post function from "Advanced Rest Client App".

API Code:

```
<?php
  require_once '../include/DbConnect.php';
  require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

  \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
  // create new Slim instance
  $app = new \Slim\Slim();

  $app->get('/users', 'getUser');
  $app->post('/register', 'addUser');



  $app->run();

  function getUser(){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
  try{
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $conn = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo '{"user": ', json_encode($users).'}';

  } catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage().'}}';
  }

}

function addUser() {
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
$user = json_decode($body);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, email) VALUES(:fname, :email)";

try{
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $conn = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("fname", $user->fname);
    $stmt->bindParam("email", $user->email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $db = null;

   echo json_encode($user);

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage().'}}';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So you want to know how to use post method from Chrome REST Client right?

Comment: @Indra have tried it but it doesn't parse those values into my post function. this the output i get {"fname":null,"email":null,"id":"25"}

Comment: The code which you have posted here doesnt process your inputs... Whats your real issue? You want to know about REST client or php code causing errors?

Comment: $user = json_decode($body); why do you decode it when that is not a json. Delete it

Comment: Okay, now i have deleted it how do i access those values in the $body = $request->getBody();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is my issue, when i echo the content of the $body in the code below these values are displayed "fname=mishael&email=mishaelharry%40gmail.com" but after i decode it with $user = json_decode($body); no values are inserted into my database and i get {"fname":null,"email":null,"id":"33"} from this line of code echo json_encode($user); [code]

```
function addUser() {
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
echo json_encode($body);
$user = json_decode($body);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, email) VALUES(:fname, :email)";

try{
    $db = new DbConnect();
    $conn = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("fname", $user->fname);
    $stmt->bindParam("email", $user->email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $user->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $db = null;

   echo json_encode($user);

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage().'}}';
}
}
```